# Use WMI to retrieve IPv4 address from computer running IPv6

Tags: vba, vbscript, wmi

I'm using VBScript to retrieve the address of a remote computer using Win32_PingStatus, like so:

```
dnsServer = "myComputerName"
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
colIpQuery = "Select * from Win32_PingStatus where Address='" + dnsServer + "' AND ResolveAddressNames=TRUE"
Set colIPAddrs = objWMIService.ExecQuery(colIpQuery)
For Each colIPAddr In colIPAddrs
    If CStr(colIpAddr.StatusCode) = 0 Then
        dnsServerIp = colIpAddr.ProtocolAddress
    End If
Next
```

The problem here is that if "myComputerName" is running IPv6, `colIpAddr.ProtocolAddress` will always return only the IPv6 address, but I need the IPv4 address. I can't disable IPv6, skip the IPv6 addresses, etc. Is there any other way to retrieve the IPv4 address without using external methods (ping, powershell, etc.)?

Comment: VBScript can't do this without external tools. I'd suggest switching to PowerShell.

Comment: That is unfortunate :( Thanks for confirming what I thought might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
' RETURN IPv4 ONLY
' ################################################
    Function getIPAddress(passedInt)
            On Error Resume Next
            Dim hostIPAddress, SQLQuery, strComputer, objWMIService, colItems
            SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE     MACAddress > '' AND IPEnabled = 'True'"
            strComputer = "."
            Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
            Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(SQLQuery)
        For Each objItem In colItems
            If IsArray( objItem.IPAddress ) Then
                If UBound( objItem.IPAddress ) = 0 Then
                    hostIPAddress = objItem.IPAddress(0)
                Else
                    hostIPAddress = "" & Join( objItem.IPAddress, "," )
                End If
            End If
        Next
        temp = split(hostIPAddress, ",")
        getIPAddress = temp(passedInt) ' temp(0) returns IPv4 Only, temp(1) retunrs IPv6 Only
    End function
```

Ive looked on multiple forums, and noone seems to mention the above

returning "obj.IPAddress" from "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" separates the values with a comma, so you can just use the Split(stringToSplit, ",") function and the reference index 0 in the array to return IPv4

```
'usage:
Dim temp, temp2
temp = getIPAddress(0)    ' temp = IPv4 address
temp2 = getIPAddress(1)   ' temp2 = IPv6 address
```